# Nonlinear things that one can do to a probability density function

Tags: probability, distributions, entropy

Say $f(x)$ is a smooth probability density function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with compact support region.  This wikipedia page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution

explains that the *entropy* of $f$ can be computed by the integral $$-\int  f(x) \log f(x) dx$$.  Also, the monograph "Probability theory and combinatorial optimization" by J.M. Steele says that the quantity $$\int f(x)^{(n-1)/n}$$ can be used to describe the length of the shortest path through a bunch of independent samples of $f$.  My question is:  are there any other non-linear operations that are commonly done to probability density functions that give useful information?  E.g., does $\int f(x)^2 dx$ tell us anything?  These are the only two examples I have come across after a lot of searching.

Comment: The Log-Sobolev inequality gives a bound on entropy and involves $f^2$ and it's gradients. See for example: http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~gentil/logsob-poincare.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Fisher Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) would be an example?  However, it only makes sense for distributions with some underlying parameter, and perhaps you don't want to make any assumptions about $f(x)$.